# Rails Fails To Generate Correct Link Path In Production Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, puma

The app whose in production mode is failed to generate correct links. 
For instance, the code below

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

is generating the code below:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/application.css" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
  <script src="/javascripts/application.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

I precompiled javascript and stylesheet. Their correct path is respectively `/public/assets/application-0d1386df5e82480bb54a6cd082e626ed2d46d364e867ca7d9ce009d3af8c1718.js` and `/public/assets/application-5d8165dcf2b8902df77aed37c7ab6fee8c7d62844cb48ece6360d1fa4f079804.css`.

Also, I did change `config.assets.compile = true` in `/config/environments/production.rb`. But nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run production mode in your local environment you should tell rails to serve assets itself by changing following

`config.serve_static_files  = true`

In production environment itself you have to configure it using nginx - http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/03/27/deploying-rails-apps-part-4-configuring-nginx/

and make sure you have reverse your earlier change before pushing it to production.

`config.serve_static_files  = false`